# PR2 Moveit Tutorial - Kinematics Plugin failed to load

Tags: ros, moveit, tutorial, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am trying to follow the PR2 MoveIt Tutorial here: docs.ros.org/api/moveit_ros_visualization/html/doc/tutorial.html. But after entering `roslaunch pr2_moveit_config demo.launch` I get various errors for each group:

```
[ERROR] [1399281344.376185685]: The kinematics plugin (left_arm) failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib/libpr2_moveit_arm_kinematics.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib/libpr2_moveit_arm_kinematics.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10kinematics14KinematicsBase9setValuesERKSsS2_S2_RKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEd)
[ERROR] [1399281344.470927551]: The kinematics plugin (left_arm_and_torso) failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib//libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib//libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10kinematics14KinematicsBase9setValuesERKSsS2_S2_RKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEd)
[ERROR] [1399281344.558265962]: The kinematics plugin (right_arm) failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib/libpr2_moveit_arm_kinematics.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib/libpr2_moveit_arm_kinematics.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10kinematics14KinematicsBase9setValuesERKSsS2_S2_RKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEd)
[ERROR] [1399281344.652086203]: The kinematics plugin (right_arm_and_torso) failed to load. Error: Failed to load library /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib//libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so. Make sure that you are calling the PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS macro in the library code, and that names are consistent between this macro and your XML. Error string: Could not load library (Poco exception = /home/kuka/Programs/moveit/devel/lib//libmoveit_kdl_kinematics_plugin.so: undefined symbol: _ZN10kinematics14KinematicsBase9setValuesERKSsS2_S2_RKSt6vectorISsSaISsEEd)
```

Rviz then continues to launch and shows the PR2. When I then continue the tutorial, I notice 3 things:

- At the end of step 1 in the tutorial, the screenshot shows that the current group is highlighted in green. This doesn't happen for me
- Even when I'm in the interact mode, I can only move the camera and nothing regarding the roboter
- No markers show up to interact with the roboter (As shown in the screenshot in step 3).

The missing library descriped in the error is in the path it is supposed to be, and I don't know what to do with the `undefined symbol`.

I am using ROS Hydro on Ubuntu 12.04 64bit, I uploaded the complete output here: gist.github.com/rabenimmermehr/0b094c1ad032cb90ac0d
(Sorry for the link formatting, I have insufficient karma)

Thanks in advance,

Rabe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/161176/pr2-moveit-tutorial---kinematics-plugin-failed-to-load/) by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 683 on 2014-05-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Seems like some packages failed to install. After a complete reinstall, everything workes as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0